# Evaluating $\lim _{z \rightarrow \infty} z e^{-\frac{1}{2} z^{2}}$ using L'Hospital's Rule

Tags: limits, normal-distribution

I'm studying normal distribution at a high school level, and I need to evaluate the limit $\lim _{z \rightarrow \infty} z e^{-\frac{1}{2} z^{2}}$

I asked this question before here, and the answer I got was that I need to use L'Hospital's Rule. From a quick Google Search, I learnt that L'Hospital's Rule is $\lim _{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim _{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{g^{\prime}(x)}$.
I tried to use it to evaluate the limit, but obviously I don't know enough about L'Hospital's Rule to do it.

I'm now just curious on how you would use L'Hospital's Rule to evaluate the limit $\lim _{z \rightarrow \infty} z e^{-\frac{1}{2} z^{2}}$. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{z\to\infty}ze^{-\frac12z^2}=\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac z{\exp\left(\frac12z^2\right)}$$
Now that we have the function in the form $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$, we can take the derivative of the numerator and denominator.
$$\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac z{\exp\left(\frac12z^2\right)}=\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac {\frac d{dz}z}{\frac d{dz}\exp\left(\frac12z^2\right)}=\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac 1{\frac d{dz}\left[\frac12z^2\right]\exp'\left(\frac12z^2\right)}=\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac 1{z\exp\left(\frac12z^2\right)}=\frac1\infty=0$$

Answer (score 4):

Take $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}$. Then $f'(x)=1$ and $g'(x)=xe^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}$, so by L'Hopital
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{e^{\frac12x^2}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{xe^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}}=0.$$

---

I'd personally not use L'Hopital for a limit like this one -- it's a bit overkill. A simpler way would be to use the series $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\dots$, so $e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}\geq1+\frac{x^2}{2}$ for $x>0$ and go from there.